# UDP Broadcast over port nnnn

Tags: c#, sockets

Trying to migrate a Delphi app to C# and can't find how to broadcast to every machine on the network using port nnnn.

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

This should set up my port address correctly.  Then I'm setting my socket options and binding the end point doing.

```
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3333));
```

but no matter what else I do on the send it doesn't seem to work.  OK... I give.  What am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send to all hosts in the subnet you have to use a `sendto` using the broadcast IP address `255.255.255.255`

see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=vs.110).aspx
It is using a UDP client which I think might be useful for you too.

And notice following statement in the link :

> Setting all the bits of an IP address to one, or 255.255.255.255, forms the limited broadcast address. Sending a UDP datagram to this address delivers the message to any host on the local network segment. Because routers never forward messages sent to this address, only hosts on the network segment receive the broadcast message.

You should end up with something like this :

```
UdpClient udp = new UdpClient();
PEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), GroupPort);

string str4 = "Is anyone out there?";
byte[] sendBytes4 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str4);
udp.Send(sendBytes4, sendBytes4.Length, groupEP);
```

The same process can be used if you use a socket directly. And you can also use `IPAddress.Broadcast` if you don't like the parse.

Comment: KEWL. Great example.  It's IPEndPoint.  but that was easy to figure out.  Thanks!

Comment: How.  See the unsanswered button but don't see the answered button.

Comment: There is a v sign right below the arrow pointing downwards which is below the 0 on the left of the answer itself. Hover over it , it turns green, click it to accept the answer.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the answer.